# Game analysis app for Mac?

Tags: analysis, software, stockfish, macos

I am using a Mac and trying to find an app that can analyse the whole game and tell me where the mistakes/inaccuracies/blunders are, instead of just telling me what I should do for the next move.

The "[Stockfish Chess for Mac](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/stockfish-chess/id801463932?mt=12)" app merely analyses the position and gives me the best move, but cannot analyse a full game.

Could someone recommend me a free app that has the above function?

Comment: This question shows a lack of research effort. I'm not downvoting though, as you are a new user. In the future, try googling first (many results for your question), before asking a new question. Welcome to the chess StackExchange. See my answer for a solution for your problem.

Comment: chess.com has done so much damage...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SCID](https://sourceforge.net/projects/scid/) or SCID vs PC if you want an app running natively on Mac.

Click Tools --> Analysis Engine. Add and configure Stockfish, then click OK.

In the engine analysis window, click on "Annotate" and configure (e.g. analysis time per move), then click OK.

There are video tutorials for this on YouTube, but I also tested this locally on my Linux machine.

However, if you do not have ChessBase / cannot run it, I would rather recommend doing it online, e.g. on chess.com (if you have a premium account) or [lichess](https://lichess.org) (40 free analyses per day), as their tools are more sophisticated than most native apps for Mac / Linux.

Comment: I think lichess is entirely free: there is no upper limit to the number of analyses you can run on it for free per day.

Comment: @insipidintegrator they probably changed it. I remember receiving the message that I have requested too many analyses for the day sometimes. Even if there may not be a limit anymore, one should not overuse their resources. But if you are completely certain, feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The software is very useful. However, as I am quite unfamiliar with configuring chess engines, how exactly do I add the Stockfish engine to SCID? I don't know how to set it up.

Comment: Hi @Hauptideal I found this: https://lichess.org/features

Comment: @JMuzhen First, you need to download Stockfish here: https://stockfishchess.org/download/
Next, you follow the instructions in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVtLn58uLus

Comment: @insipidintegrator great, so we know its 40 analyses.